# Import a number of csv files and replace NA by Zeros

Tags: r

I know how to do this individually. However, I have more than 1000 files. I decided to use a for loop. However, it seems like I did not find the correct way to evaluate my variables.

Here is my code

```
setwd('C:/data')
filenames=dir() #find file names

for (i in filenames){
  adt = substr(x = i, start = 1, stop = nchar(i)-4)
  name=paste("data_", adt, sep="")
  assign(name, read.csv(i,header=T,sep=",")) #read each file and assign a variable name starting with data_ to it
  func=paste('name[is.na(name)] <- 0',sep="") # here is the place I have problem. R will not consider name is a parameter whose values change in each iteration
  eval((text=func))

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the results of `read.csv` to a temporary variable, replace the `NA`s, then assign to `name`

```
for (i in filenames){
  adt = substr(x = i, start = 1, stop = nchar(i)-4)
  name=paste("data_", adt, sep="")
  tmp <- read.csv(i, header=TRUE, sep=",")
  tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
  assign(name, tmp, pos=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why R will not consider parameter name as a dynamic one? (or why my code failed?)

Comment: Maybe `paste0(name, "[is.na(", name, ")] <- 0")` would work.  Also, you probably don't want 2 sets of parentheses in the `eval` line (and you probably don't want to use `eval`). [FAQ 7.21](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f) may help clear up some confusion.

Comment: for loops are terribly inefficient, especially when you have > 1000 files. vectorize the operation instead.

Comment: @GSee yes, vectorization is a horrible idea. for loops are way to go. You win.

Comment: @Maiasaura Of course you want to vectorize when you can, but you can't here.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)
# change the pattern to match whatever file type you are reading
filenames <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = ".csv", all.files = FALSE, 
full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE)
data <- llply(filenames, read.csv)
cleaned_data <- llply(data, function(x)  {x[is.na(x)] <- 0; return(x)})
names(cleaned_data) <- paste0("data_", 1:length(cleaned_data))
```

Comment: This is not vectorized.  The `llply` function just hides the loop from you.

Comment: +1 for using a list to store the results in stead of relying on assign and several variables.